# Discord.js How to add customemoji inside embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

<:fly:714097004367839282> when i add it show :fly: how to fix?

```
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#16E9DE')
    .setTitle('<:fly:714097004367839282> Helo bot <:fly:714097004367839282> ')
    .setAuthor('Bot hello')
    .setDescription('<:fly:714097004367839282> Hello <:fly:714097004367839282>')
    .setThumbnail('')
    .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter('BeamKunGzMARK#3855', 'https://i.imgur.com/POZeOUa.png');
```

Comment: The syntax looks correct. Curious that it displays `:fly:` rather than the full unformatted text. Is that custom emoji from a server that the bot is in? If it's from a server that you are in but the bot is not in, then you'll be able to use it (with Nitro) but the bot won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bot need to inside your server emoji custom too

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the custom emoji before using it

```js
const flyEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get('714097004367839282')
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#16E9DE')
    .setTitle(`${flyEmoji} Helo bot ${flyEmoji}`)
    .setAuthor('Bot hello')
    .setDescription(`${flyEmoji} Hello ${flyEmoji}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('BeamKunGzMARK#3855', 'https://i.imgur.com/POZeOUa.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do add the intents to get Emojis :

```
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
    ]
});
```

next you do `\:emoji:` on discord to take ID and name

next, on your embed :

```
.addField("<:name:id> blabla.....")
```